# C# - way to pass property of the generic type like an enum

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, properties

I have a model which stores `Id` (`Int64`; for SQLite id column), `Description` (`string`), `DueDate` (`DateTime?`; null if not specified), and `IsFinished` (`bool`), such as

`TodoItem.cs`

```cs
public record TodoItem(Int64 Id, string Description, DateTime? DueDate = null, bool IsFinished = false);
```

and a ViewModel for the model.

`TodoItemViewModel.cs`

```cs
public class TodoItemViewModel
{
    Int64 _id;
    string _description;
    DateTime? _dueDate;
    bool _isFinished;

    public Int64 Id => _id;
    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _description, value);
        }
    }

    // omits for DueDate, IsFinished properties
}
```

I want call the Database's update command when each property's setter executed. I am looking for some fancy way to pass 'which property to update'. **Is there a feature for to pass property of the generic type `T` like an enum?** Code below for the example.

```cs
// The Type PropertyField<T> is my virtual thought
void Update(Int64 id, PropertyField<TodoItem> property, object value)
{
    string sql = $"UPDATE tablename SET {property.PropertyName} = {value} WHERE id = {id}";
    // execute sql command...
}
```

And call it by

`TodoItemViewModel.cs`

```cs
    // ...

    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _description, value);
            Update(Id, TodoItem.Description, value); // update the description as new value for current todo item
        }
    }


    // ...
```

It would be great if I can specify the corresponding type of the value (not `object`, but `string` for the above example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to take an [expression tree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) `Expression<Func<TodoItem, T>>` as the parameter.

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;

void Update<T>(Int64 id, Expression<Func<TodoItem, T>> property, T value) {
    ...
}

// example usage:
Update(someId, x => x.Description, newDescription);
```

Note that you get autocomplete for the properties of the record when you are typing `x => x.`, and you'd get a compiler error if you make a typo. I'm assuming this is what you mean by "like an enum".

To get the name of the property from the expression tree, you can do:

```
if (property.Body is MemberExpression memberExpression) {
    var name = memberExpression.Member.Name
    // use name in the SQL query...
} else {
    // the root of the expression isn't a member expression!
    // perhaps throw an exception?
}
```

Note that it is possible to pass an expression tree whose root isn't a member access, and the compiler won't complain. For example:

```
x => x.Description + x.IsFinished
```

In this case, the root of the expression tree is a "+" expression, and it is unclear what the "name" of this expression is. This is currently handled by the `else` branch in the code above.

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671968/retrieving-property-name-from-lambda-expression) for other ways of getting the name from an expression tree.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. My intention to use the word 'enum' means the property should be suggested by compiler's IntelliSense and you caught it. For every time I think C# has great language features!